# WordPress multi site installation

Tags: php, wordpress

i have 3 self hosted wordpress sites in same machine but each one uses different url as explained below.

```
publication.mysite.com  (wordpress site)
info.mysite.com (wordpress site)
flipbook.mysite.com (wordpress site)
```

now mysite.com is our primary company's website. it is a sharepoint site. because of this i cannot create mysite.com as our primary wordpress site.

i want to keep publication.mysite.com as our primary wordpress site and under this site bring the other 2 wordpress sites (multi-installation).

below is what in am trying to accomplish.

- all 3 sites should consume it's own mysql database
- all should be pointing to it's directory
- all 3 sites url should not changed.
- all posts, and other data in all 3 sites must be retained.

how could i do this? i tried to follow wordpress multisite installation documentation but i am stuck because i do not know how to setup as per my domain requirement.

another reason why i want to do this because of search. i have a global site search plugin from wpmudev. we need the ability to search from any one of our site to other 2 sites. for example: if i am searching for a 'productA'in one site, i need to display all post related to 'productA' from other 2 sites as well.

if there is any better way to perform global search like i explained, then i would like to hear about it

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why do you want to have each site on a separate database? I think you'd be better off leaving them on the same database in WPMU. It's optimized for that. You could probably tweak WordPress to do otherwise but I don't see any upside.

Comment: the 3 sites are already deployed to production and have 1000's of post in each. how can i migrate all the data to the same database in wpmu?

Comment: i am .Net developer and our php guy is not longer with us. i have very little knowledge about wordpress and mysql

Comment: With very little knowledge about WordPress it may feel like an impossible task. What I'd do is export/import on WordPress admin, or if you have a lot of custom settings, migrate your tables from each database (`mysqldump` or you can do it using GUI with MySQL Workbench or PHPMyAdmin), generate new sites using WPMU, and replace your tables with the tables generated, tweaking `wp_options` table as I went along to set the correct URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Your network-wide search functionality will be difficult to achieve if you must use separate databases for each site. It will require development chops that most people don't have. I respectfully suggest you reconsider that requirement.

Multisite search, in a single database, can be done with a plugin. For example. https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-global-search/

A WordPress multisite installation is designed to host sites with varying URLs. The migration isn't hard to do. You set up the target multisite system with three sites (blogs, WordPress's documentation calls them) in it. Rig the URLs for each of them.

This document explains the path to follow. https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network Multisite's administrative menu offers ways to configure the individual sites.

You then export the content from the individual sites and import them, one by one, into the target sites.

WordPress is decently well documented. Read this for an outline of the process of migrating to multisite. https://codex.wordpress.org/Migrating_Multiple_Blogs_into_WordPress_3.0_Multisite

Comment: ok, let's say i keep the same database. but could you please point me in the direction on how i can keep the same urls like i explained above? Thank you for your help and suggestions